# What is the ipn url for the paypal express checkout in magento

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal express checkout in magento as payment method.
I have set the ipn url as `http://mymagentosite.com/paypal/ipn/`.

I am getting the emails from the paypal as

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

```
http://mymagentosite.com/paypal/ipn/
```

What is the correct url that I should set for my site?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
YOUR_BASE_URL/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/
```

Comment: I my url  Iam missing index.php and in the last /index/ does this make any difference?

Comment: index.php does not make any difference but /index you have to add because it is action of controller where paypal start its action

Comment: you may also write YOUR_BASE_URL/paypal/ipn/index/

Comment: I will try your suggestion

Comment: Hello Guys, I have added the index action at the end like BASE_URL//paypal/ipn/index but still I am getting the IPN error message from the PayPal, could you please help me to resolve this.